# Unknown error when trying to register a Minecraft ArmorItem

Tags: java, minecraft-modding

The error in question is [***Inferred type 'I' for type parameter 'I' is not within its bound; should extend 'net.minecraft.item.Item'***]

on the following snippet of code

```
// Armor Items
public static final RegistryObject<ArmorItem> RINGMAIL_HELMET = ITEMS.register("ringmail_helmet",
        new ArmorItem(DnDCraftArmorMaterial.RINGMAIL, EquipmentSlotType.HEAD, new Item.Properties().group(DnDCraft.TAB)));
```

I have tried many things like what I do here

```
public static final RegistryObject<Item> RING = ITEMS.register("ring", ItemBase::new);
```

by putting the **ItemBase::new** snippet in the last paramter.
I've also tried seeing what IntelliJ suggests is best in-context action but none of those approaches seemed to fix the issue.

I'm not super familiar with Java or Minecraft modding so this may just be something simple that I am missing but any help or recommendations would be nice. Thanks!

Also this is the ItemBase class, in case that helps.

```
package com.fire.dndcraft.items;

import com.fire.dndcraft.DnDCraft;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemGroup;

public class ItemBase extends Item {
    public ItemBase() {
        super(new Item.Properties().group(DnDCraft.TAB));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem have you figured this out yet?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, try adding `() ->` after the comma that's after the `ringmail_helmet` but don't add another comma

```
public static final RegistryObject<ArmorItem> RINGMAIL_HELMET = ITEMS.register("ringmail_helmet", () ->
        new ArmorItem(DnDCraftArmorMaterial.RINGMAIL, EquipmentSlotType.HEAD, new Item.Properties().group(DnDCraft.TAB)));
```